Office js add-in checking if the current user has purchased a related subscription
I'm working on an Excel addin that has a free set of basic features and an advanced set that can be purchased by subscription.
I see that I can do that using the Commercial Marketplace with a SaaS subscription so I can maintain a database of subscribed users on my site.
In the Excel addin, I can use the SSO samples to call getToken(), check if that user is listed in my database of subscribed users and if so, display the 'pro' features.
But when I call getToken() in the add-in, does that add towards the Azure MAU count for my tenant (whether they have a subscription or not)? I know I get 50,000 MAUs for free, but I have no way to predict how many people might try out the addin or stick using the free, basic features, and could end up with a nasty bill.
Is there any other (free) way that I can get the current user's identity, that I could check against my db of subscribed users?

I'm trying to get some information internally at Microsoft. In the meantime, try asking the question at Microsoft Q&A.  Also, this might be something to ask on SuperUser or on the help for your Azure account.

Thanks Rick. I've just asked in Microsoft Q&A (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1643847/office-js-add-in-checking-if-the-current-user-has). I raised a support ticket with the Azure team and their response was "We've asked everyone here and nobody knows for sure. Try reaching out to the Office add-in technical team to see if they can help". Do you know if the Office SSO can work with a basic "Azure AD B2C" tenant - that only seems to have an 'openid' scope and not 'profile'.

I'm still trying to track down who knows the answer. (It's a big company!)

I've finally got an answer. Calls of getToken do count towards the MAU limit. For cost management, I'm passing along this suggestion: ""about how to monitor the usage, setup alarms for certain amounts and also maybe implement a feature in the add-in that checks for subscription status before calling the getToken() as these could help manage the MAU count."

Thanks very much for tracking down the answer. I will indeed take the advice of setting up such alarms and checking subscription status.

This is particularly the case for the "Azure B2C" tenant type, which listed MAU counts as something charged for. If I have a Microsoft 365 tenant, does that also have any MAU-related charges, or is there just the flat Office users' subscription charge with no additional costs if use it that tenant for userToken SSO verification?
